# Bootstrap modal is showing as disabled when I use id=footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Bootstrap modal is working fine but when I add footer tags then its showing but as disabled
[Her is a image of how the modal is displayed in web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7PyZ.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
<!--footer started-->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="footer">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1" href="#" >Disclaimer</a>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal1" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    Disclaimer</h4>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                THIS SITE IS THE PROPERTY OF domain.COM. ANY REPRODUCTION
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <!--modal-2-->  
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2" href="#" >Terms of Use</a>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal2" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    Terms of Use</h4>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                THIS SITE IS THE PROPERTY OF domain.COM. ANY REPRODUCTION
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div><!--container-->
</div><!--row-->
</div><!--footer-->
<!--footer ended-->
```

Please advise as to why modal is not working with footer id. Yes here is my footer css:

```
/**footer**/
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 450;
  margin: 0px auto;
  bottom: 25; 
  margin-top:50; 
  background-color:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is simple put your modals outside of your footer div.

```css
/**footer**/

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 450;
  margin: 0px auto;
  bottom: 25;
  margin-top: 50;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    Disclaimer</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        THIS SITE IS THE PROPERTY OF domain.COM. ANY REPRODUCTION
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal2" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    Terms of Use</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        THIS SITE IS THE PROPERTY OF domain.COM. ANY REPRODUCTION
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<!--footer started-->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="footer">
      <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1" href="#">Disclaimer</a>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <!--modal-2-->
      <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2" href="#">Terms of Use</a>


    </div>
    <!--container-->
  </div>
  <!--row-->
</div>
<!--footer-->
<!--footer ended-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
#modal2 {
  z-index: 2147483647;
}
```

Comment: I added but no change

Comment: So try increasing z-index value for modal2 to its maximum. Its, i think, 2147483647

Comment: still no luck. Can you please elaborate your answer

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.

Comment: Increasing z index will not solve this problem as it is not even being show on click in original code.